# Repelling or attracting spiral phase portrait in canonical basis

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

If matrix $\bf{A}$ of a system $\bf{x}'=\bf{A}x$ (*) has only complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors with non-zero real parts, and we make the substitution $\bf{y}'=\bf{B}x$ (**), where $\bf{B=P^{-1}AP}$, then will the phase portrait of the spiral be the same in case (*) and case (**)?

Comment: **No** if the first system lives in $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

If you extend the first system to $\mathbb C^n$, the phase portraits will be the "same" topologically and differentiably. The fact that the eigenvectors have nonzero real parts is irrelevant, although of course unavoidable. Note: This answer assumes that your first matrix has only real entries.

Comment: But how can we draw the basis eigenvectors relative to the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ if they are complex?

Comment: You can't if the eigenvectors are not in $\mathbb R^n$. Unavoidably, you need to consider the first system in $\mathbb C^n$ for that.

Comment: The first system is in $\mathbb{R}^n$ . What do you mean when you say consider it in $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: Extend it to $\mathbb C^n$: $(x+iy)'=A(x+iy)$, defining $A(x+iy)=Ax+iAy$.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand how exactly this works. Once we have this extended system, what do we do?

Comment: Sorry, you really have to be more specific, since there is nothing different here.

Comment: If we have a system $x'=Ax$ with complex eigenvalues and complex corresponding eigenvectors, how can we draw the eigenvectors to determine the bases of the phase portraits?

Comment: You think of $\mathbb C^n$ as $\mathbb R^{2n}$ and you draw the phase portrait in $\mathbb R^{2n}$.

Comment: If we have two complex eigenvectors, then the phase portrait is a spiral in two dimensions. How can it be drawn in four dimensions?

Comment: That is the answer to what you asked. But you can recover the original solution (and original phase portrait) but taking the real part of $x+iy$. Recall that you were the one asking about the system $y'=Bx$. Overall it is not a good approach to draw the phase portrait, but if you read your question again, you asked something very different. I regret that I have to leave it here.